# Fetching data from a table alphabetically using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is there a way to fetch data from a table alphabetically using webdriver.

for example:

a table contains "sno, language, text, link"

I would like to know is there away to fetch data alphabetically using language as the column. Lets say the languages are not alphabetically  ordered... Russian, Spanish, English, Chinese... ETC

Comment: do you mean an html table?

Comment: It's probably easier to dump everything into a list of webelements then sort them, would that be something you could use?

Comment: If they're going to be in a mixture of Cyrillic, Latin, and Han Chinese alphabets, you're going to have a hard time defining what "alphabetically"" means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a DataStructure to store the WebElements which are getting listed while finding elements of table.

For Java you can use a DataStructure like HashMap where you can save the link texts as the Key later you can use Collection.sort to sort this DataStructure with the attribute/ column you want.